# How to manage a bookstore

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, terms

I am planning to make a bookstore website with Wordpress.

Can you give me some advice to manage my store?

I'm not sure whether to choose Custom Post Type or Custom Taxonomy to manage the authors of the book. Because a book can be written by many authors and an author will write many different books.

I would like to have a separate page for each author and when the user clicks on each author's link, he / she will have information about that author and the books he wrote, and also in the product page I want Add suggestions to customers about books with the author.

So I should create a custom Custom Post Type to manage the author and link to Woocommerce or I should create 1 Woocommerce Taxanomy (like the Catalog) to manage and display authors and books as I want above.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the author should be a taxonomy to me. You can have multiple authors to one book and multiple books to one or multiple authors, just like you can do with tags.